# Splitting a plotly violin plot by more than two groups

Tags: r, split, plotly, violin-plot

My question is about expanding `R` `plotly`'s [grouped violin plot](https://plotly.com/r/violin/) to a case with more than two groups.

Taking the data that are used in the [grouped violin plot example code](https://plotly.com/r/violin/) and adding a third `level` to `df$sex`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/violin_data.csv")
df <- df %>%
  rbind(df[sample(nrow(df), 100, replace = F),] %>%
          dplyr::mutate(sex = "undefined", day = sample(df$day, 100 , replace = F), day = sample(df$day, 100, replace = F)))
df$sex <- factor(df$sex)
```

Trying to plot this with:

```
plotly::plot_ly(x = df$day, y = df$total_bill, type = 'violin', split = df$sex, color = df$sex)
```

I get the violins of each of the sexes centered rather than split:
[image]

And this remains the case if I switch `split = df$sex` to `name = df$sex`.

But if I change `type = 'violin'` to `type = 'bar'` I do get `df$sex` split:
[image]

Any idea how to get this to work for the `type = 'violin'` case?

Comment: It works fine for me if you follow the code they give on the page they linked?

Comment: Quick test suggests you need the `%>% layout(violinmode = 'group')` that is used in the example you link.